On the functional equation and analytic continuation of the Eisenstein series $E(z,s)$
Zagier says that $$E^\ast (z,s):=\pi^{-s} \Gamma(s)\zeta(2s)E(z,s)$$ $$=\dfrac{1}{2} \pi^{-s}\Gamma(s)\sum_{m,n}' Q_z(m,n)^{-s}$$ $$=\dfrac{1}{2} \pi^{-s}\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt \sum_{m,n}' Q_z(m,n)^{-s}$$ $$=\dfrac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty (\Theta_z(t)-1)t^{s-1} dt ,$$ where $$Q_z(m,n)=\dfrac{|mz+n|^2}{y}$$ is a quadratic form and $$\Theta_z(t)=\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-\pi tQ_z(m,n)}$$ is the corresponding theta-series.
The first equality is a definition and the second one and third one I understood. However, I don't see the last equality and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me. I tried to do the math and "join" the two sides, but I couldn't solve it. How can I get that integral?

We have, assuming you know how to justify the exchange sum-integral:
$$\begin{split}\int_0^\infty (\Theta_z(t)-1)t^{s-1} \mathrm{d}t &= \int_0^\infty \left(\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z} \atop (m,n) \neq (0,0)} e^{-\pi tQ_z(m,n)}\right)t^{s-1} \mathrm{d}t\\
&= \sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z} \atop (m,n) \neq (0,0)} \int_0^\infty e^{-\pi tQ_z(m,n)}t^{s-1} \mathrm{d}t\\
&= \sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z} \atop (m,n) \neq (0,0)} \int_0^\infty e^{-\pi tQ_z(m,n)}(\pi tQ_z(m,n))^{s-1} (\pi Q_z(m,n))^{-(s-1)}\mathrm{d}t\\
&= \sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z} \atop (m,n) \neq (0,0)} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{s-1} (\pi Q_z(m,n))^{-(s-1)} (\pi Q_z(m,n))^{-1}\mathrm{d}u\\
&= \pi^{-s}\left(\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z} \atop (m,n) \neq (0,0)} Q_z(m,n)^{-s}\right)\int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{s-1} \mathrm{d}u\end{split}$$
where $u = \pi Q_z(m,n)t$ so that $\mathrm{d}t = (\pi Q_z(m,n))^{-1} \mathrm{d}u$.

Right, thank you so much. But in the first equality, $(\Theta_z(t)-1)t^{s-1}$ is equal to $t^{s-1}\Theta_z(t)-t^{s-1}$, isn't?
And the change sum-integral is because of the Monotone convergence theorem, isn't? Just to check.

@AndreiDoronin The term in $\Theta_z(t)$ corresponding to $(m,n) = (0,0)$ gives $1$, which is where the $-1$ from the integrand comes into play and why there's one less term in the sum. As for the swapping sum-integral, yes that would be one way.

YES, YES, YES! I understood! Thank you so much!
